# How do I do address normalizations?

Tags: ruby, street-address

I'm interacting with two APIs, which return addresses that are formatted quite differently. One returns an address like "`6 Avenue`" and another returns "`6 Ave.`"

I explored using the Normalic gem, but for some reason many of my addresses are returned malformed or blank: "`6 Avenue`" gets returned as "`Ave.`".

I also tried GeoCoder, but each API such as Google and Yahoo have set quotas. After a few hours of testing my app in development, these quotas expire. This obviously won't do in production.

It would be great if there was a library that let me do something like evaluate `"6 Ave." == "6 Avenue"`.

Comment: Do you mean 6th Ave? Normalic should handle that. As written it looks like it's missing the street name.

Answer (score 4):

For US addresses, the USPS offers [an address api](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm?). My understanding is that there is no charge, but your purpose needs to be for use with an e commerce website to validate addesses as they're entered.

For cleaning databases, the USPS often sends you to one of their (expensive) service providers for mailers.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby StreetAddress gem should take care of this for you: https://rubygems.org/gems/StreetAddress

Here's some example usage for your case:

```
pry(main)> StreetAddress::US.parse("42 6 Ave., Washington, DC")
=> 42 6 Ave, Washington, DC
pry(main)> StreetAddress::US.parse("42 6 Avenue, Washington, DC")
=> 42 6 Ave, Washington, DC
```

So if you run both of your API addresses through the parse method, it should standardize both for you, and free up your life for more reflection, biking, and pizza consumption.

Comment: Just a word of caution for those looking for a parser gem: from what I can tell, you won't find a 100% solution nor even 80% solution unless you go to the online APIs such as the USPS one or MelissaData (neither of which I've tried out). StreetAddress, for example, doesn't handle unit / apartment / suite numbers great, and breaks altogether if a C/O, Attn: or PO box are provided. We've settled on Normalic because it's more tolerant of malformed inputs, but still not super happy.

Comment: I agree with Topher about a parser gem not being very reliable. I am a software developer for SmartyStreets, which provides an address validation and standardization API like MelissaData does, and I can tell you getting reliable standardization is a tougher problem than it appears to be.